# PostgreSQL UPDATE Statement Error Despite Reading Documentation

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to update an array in an array in a column. However, psycopg2 keeps erroring, and I have no clue as to why this statement errors like this.

The Code:

```
lastUpload = "tgpx60236wa"
print(search.execute()["items"][0]["contentDetails"]["upload"]["videoId"])
connect = psycopg2.connect(host = loadConfig()["host"], database = loadConfig()["database"], user = loadConfig()["user"], password = loadConfig()["password"])
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute(f"SELECT youtube_channels[{channels.index(channel)}][1] FROM youtubeChannels WHERE guild_id = {guild[0]}")
print(cursor.fetchone()[0])
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE youtubeChannels SET youtube_channels[{channels.index(channel)}] = {lastUpload} WHERE guild_id = {guild[0]} RETURNING youtube_channels;")
connect.commit()
print(cursor.fetchone()[0])
cursor.close()
connect.close()
```

The Output:

```
cursor.execute(f"UPDATE youtubeChannels SET youtube_channels[{channels.index(channel)}] = {lastUpload} WHERE guild_id = {guild[0]} RETURNING youtube_channels;")
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "tgpx60236wa" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE youtubeChannels SET youtube_channels[0] = tgpx60236wa...
```

I don't even know what this error is supposed to mean, but I just don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Most people dont like horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Right now, you seem to be missing single quotes in the query around `{lastUpload}`. You should use prepared statements so you don't need to worry about this anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're not supposed to inform parameters on psycopg2 queries using f-Strings. The query parameters supposed to be passed as arguments of the `execute` method and using placeholders for the substitution, something like this:

```
lastUpload = "tgpx60236wa"
print(search.execute()["items"][0]["contentDetails"]["upload"]["videoId"])
connect = psycopg2.connect(host = loadConfig()["host"], database = loadConfig()["database"], user = loadConfig()["user"], password = loadConfig()["password"])
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT youtube_channels[%s][1] FROM youtubeChannels WHERE guild_id = %s", channels.index(channel), guild[0])
print(cursor.fetchone()[0])
cursor.execute("UPDATE youtubeChannels SET youtube_channels[%s] = %s WHERE guild_id = %s RETURNING youtube_channels;", channels.index(channel), lastUpload, guild[0])
connect.commit()
print(cursor.fetchone()[0])
cursor.close()
connect.close()
```

Note that this isn't the only way you can pass parameters to a sql query. I suggest you take a dive in the [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) to understand better.